# c# Какой максимальный размер можно задать массиву типа byte[]?

Tags: c#, массивы, byte, bytearray

Следующий код вызывает исключение -"Переполнение в результате выполнения арифметической операции":

```
 byte[] aByte = new byte[ulong.MaxValue];
```

Сколько максимум элементов может иметь одномерный массив байт в c#? Как его можно расширить, если недостаточно стандартных границ? использовать многомерные массивы?

Comment: Даже если этот код бы сработал, то откуда у вас 18 экзабайт оперативной памяти?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По-умолчанию максимальный размер массива в памяти 2 Гигабайта. На 64-битных системах это ограничение можно обойти, если включить в файле конфигурации `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` в `configuration/runtime`. Но массив все равно не сможет содержать больше чем 4 милиарда элементов.

Придется создавать массив массивов. Многомерный массив не поможет, так на него работают те же самые ограничения, что и на одномерный.

Взято отсюда: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx

> By default, the maximum size of an Array is 2 gigabytes (GB). In a
>   64-bit environment, you can avoid the size restriction by setting the
>   enabled attribute of the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects configuration element
>   to true in the run-time environment. However, the array will still be
>   limited to a total of 4 billion elements, and to a maximum index of
>   0X7FEFFFFF in any given dimension (0X7FFFFFC7 for byte arrays and
>   arrays of single-byte structures).