# Ошибка при чтении большого файла в память

Tags: c#

У меня файл больше 10 гиг. Хочу залить содержимое в память. Сделал проект 64х битным. Озу 256 гиг

В какой то момент времени выдаёт ошибку `OutOfMemoryException`. Что может быть не так? Объем используемого озу максиму гиг 15

```
var lst = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       lst.Add(line);
    }
}
```

PS После долгих тестов увидел что список вмещает в себя максимум `134217728` строк. Какое-то системное ограничение. Как его обойти?

Comment: А почему `lst.Add(z);` а не `lst.Add(line);` ?

Comment: @Bulson опечатка

Comment: А какая версия фреймворка? До 4.5 было ограничение на 2GB на объект. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808946/out-of-memory-exception-on-64bit

Comment: Причины могут быть очень разными. Можете подсказать, среднюю длину одной строки в файле. Навскидку. И версию рантайма.

Comment: длина 10 символов

Comment: Может надежнее воспользоваться [Memory-mapped files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Сколько строчек в файле?

Comment: 134217728 строк в списке- почему-то такое ограничение

Comment: задайте Capacity в конструкторе списка, поможет меньше памяти использовать т.к. там при заполнении он увеличивает внутренний массив и копирует все что было в новый.. 
А вообще, насколько вам важно все это дело держать в списке и потом отдавать в обработку? Рассмотрите возможность обработки в ленивом режиме используя IEnumerable<string> и yield return line;

Comment: делаю 999999999 - выдаёт ошибку @SultanovShamil

Comment: @Radzhab, такое ограничение объяснимо. Чтобы хранить в списке 134217728 строк, необходимо выделить массив размером в 134217728 * sizeof(IntPtr), то есть выделится 134217728 * 8, что равно ровно 1ГБ. Как только Вы пытаетесь добавить ещё одну строку в список, метод List.ensureCapacity пытается выделить массив размером в Count * 2 элементов, то есть в Вашем случае — 2ГБ, если прибавить сюда память, расходуемую CLR на служебные данные, объект получается чуть больше 2ГБ. Если Вы используете .NET Framework 4.5.1 и позже, Вам должна помочь установка настройки gcAllowVeryLargeObjects в true.

Comment: @Radzhab, скорее всего Вам поможет ответ на этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826474/c-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-byte

Comment: Предлагаю использовать `LinkedList\`1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В App.config добавил следующий код и все заработало

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```